# how to do something like multiple views ..stack in iOS on Android?

Tags: android, ios, android-layout

I was wondering about the following situation:

in iOS:

I have viewA which goes to viewB on button press. from view B based on some computations, I can either go to viewC or go back to viewA.

I have done this nicely on iOS.

I am wondering how to do the same in Android. Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the Task stack on android. Take a look to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html), it will be what you're looking for.

For example (I've encapsulate this in a Navigation Manager instance, that handles all my navigation logic, but given your context, something like this could be useful:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.activityC, ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //THIS IS THE TASK MANAGEMENT
if (!params.isEmpty())
    intent.putExtras(params);
this.activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: sorry about my late response, I've edited my response with a piece of code. Let me know if you have any other issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Task Stack in Android is correct. If you need to specifically know how to move from one activity to another then just use intents like this to change to a new activity:

```
    Intent startActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(), TargetActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(startActivity, 0);
```